# apt upgrade in wsl uses 100% disk, uses hardly any memory, and takes over an hour to complete

Tags: memory, ssd, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

Today I reinstalled Windows, and when setting up my WSL environment I noticed things were taking *really long* when unpacking packages as part of `apt upgrade`. I checked task manager and found the following:

[image]

This seems very wrong - 100% active time, but not much transferring of data. And hardly any memory usage. As I'm typing this, the progress of `apt upgrade` is at 26% after running for nearly an hour. This is running off a SN850 Gen 4 SSD, so there should be no reason for the slowness.

This wasn't a problem before I reinstalled windows, so I know nothing is wrong with the hardware.

The real kicker - I formatted the partition and reinstalled Windows *again*, and am still experiencing the same problem.

My only idea is to format the entire drive instead of this one partition, but I don't see why that would be necessary, so I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Please add a tag to indicate WSL1 or WSL2.  They are different beasts.

Comment: As the Señor said, would like to know if this is WSL1 or 2, but either way, try a `wsl --export <distroname> <filename.tar>` -- Does it complete without issue or have similar problems?

Comment: For reference the issue is with WSL 2. I am having the same issue with `apt update` and tried to export the distro and same thing is happeneiong.